# Failed building wheel for zstandard

Tags: android, mobile

```
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Building wheel for zstandard (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [25 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\zstandard
      copying zstandard\cffi.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\zstandard
      copying zstandard\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\zstandard
      running build_ext
      building 'zstd' extension
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\c-ext
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\zstd
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\zstd\common
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\zstd\compress
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\zstd\decompress
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\zstd\dictBuilder
      "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.36.32532\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Izstd\common -Izstd\decompress -Izstd\dictBuilder -Izstd\compress -Ic-ext -Izstd -IC:\Python311\include -IC:\Python311\Include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.36.32532\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.36.32532\ATLMFC\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\cppwinrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um" /Tcc-ext\bufferutil.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\c-ext\bufferutil.obj -DZSTD_MULTITHREAD -DZSTDLIB_VISIBILITY= -DZDICTLIB_VISIBILITY= -DZSTDERRORLIB_VISIBILITY=
      bufferutil.c
      c-ext\bufferutil.c(761): error C2106: '=': left operand must be l-value
      c-ext\bufferutil.c(769): error C2106: '=': left operand must be l-value
      c-ext\bufferutil.c(777): error C2106: '=': left operand must be l-value
      c-ext\bufferutil.c(785): error C2106: '=': left operand must be l-value
      error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.36.32532\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for zstandard
Failed to build zstandard
ERROR: Could not build wheels for zstandard, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

I'm trying to install MobSF and while installing the requirement I'm stuck in this error.